# how to set specific version of node as default using n

Tags: node.js, npm

I've installed `node` using the `npm` by below commands.

```
  sudo npm cache clean -f
  sudo npm install -g n
  sudo n 8
```

`sudo n 8` installed `node 8` .

```
$ sudo n 8
 install : node-v8.11.3
   mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/8.11.3
   fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.3/node-v8.11.3-darwin-x64.tar.gz
   ######################################################################## 100.0%
  installed : v6.13.1
```

but didn't set it as default

```
 $ node -v
 v6.13.1
```

How can I set node version 8 as default node version.

Comment: try `which node` there must be a symlink to change the exec

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You still need to activate the installed version, installing doesn't automatically switch to that version. Type `n` after doing the install and select the version you want. From that point forward, it will be the node version your system uses. You may need to use `sudo n` if you run into permission issues.

Comment: @AndrewLi Yeah but, like I said in my answer, you need to run it a second time. The first time just installs it.

Comment: I run multiple times 'sudo n 8' but node version is still the same.

Comment: peteb - I'm sorry. Your suggestion is working. I've specifically set node@6 in PATH. I removed now and it is working :)

Comment: Also make sure you either reload your bashrc `source ~/.bashrc`, or start a new terminal session.

Comment: Does this still work in 2021? I just tried it a few times and restarted my session a few times but it didn't work. Could there be a setting somewhere on my system (other than `.bashrc`) that's forcing my node to be a specific version?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I couldn't change the node version because I installed node through `brew`, and was then trying to change the version through `n` (another node version manager, similar to `nvm`).

All I had to do was:
`brew uninstall node`

After this, I just had to run:
`sudo n 18.14.1`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NVM, you can have multiple versions of nodejs and it's pretty easy to manage.

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Don't forget to remove nvm before you install n. For me that is why it wouldn't change the node version.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, i've deleted node package that was installed with system package manager (yum).